# Port Mapped IO read value is not same as write value

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to understand Memory Mapped IO and Port Mapped IO. I found the below code online, which is trying to write and read a free memory address in Port mapped IO.

```
#define IOSTART  0x200
#define IOEXTEND 0x40

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/ioport.h>
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

static unsigned long iostart = IOSTART, ioextend = IOEXTEND, ioend;
module_param(iostart, ulong, S_IRUGO);
module_param(ioextend, ulong, S_IRUGO);

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    unsigned long ultest = (unsigned long)100;
    ioend = iostart + ioextend;

    pr_info(" requesting the IO region from 0x%lx to 0x%lx\n",
        iostart, ioend);

    if (!request_region(iostart, ioextend, "my_ioport")) {
        pr_info("the IO REGION is busy, quitting\n");
        return -EBUSY;
    }

    pr_info(" writing a long=%ld\n", ultest);
    outl(ultest, iostart);

    ultest = inl(iostart);
    pr_info(" reading a long=%ld\n", ultest);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
    pr_info(" releasing  the IO region from 0x%lx to 0x%lx\n",
        iostart, ioend);
    release_region(iostart, ioextend);
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Jerry Cooperstein");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");
```

Why is the read data not same as write data. Can you please help me to understand.

```
[12336.695852]  requesting the IO region from 0x200 to 0x240
[12336.695854]  writing a long=100
[12336.695869]  reading a long=4294967295
```

Comment: You had mixed XYZ in one place. First of all, I/O **is not** memory, even MMIO. The latter is using same access mechanism from CPU point of view, but has different meaning on hardware level. Second, I/O implies a **hardware** to be presented and connected and addressed respectively. What you are doing is some ambiguity.

Comment: *"Why is the read data not same as write data."* -- The peripheral device could provide access to different registers for read versus write for the same address. For an example see this [16550D UART datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pc16550d.pdf), where on page 17, a write of address 2 accesses the FCR, whereas a read of address 2 accesses the IIR.  Actually this is not specific to port I/O, but rather device specific; a memory-mapped connection to this chip would behave the same.